# How to make a proxy (low poly object just for display) in blender 2.8?

Tags: rendering, objects, particles

i'm wondering how to make proxies in blender.
**in all other software, a proxy object is a low poly object displayed only in the viewport, for replacing a too demanding asset** just in the viewport. in the rendered view or final render only the complex object is loaded.

like this example below.

[image] 
[image]

How to do that in blender ? the technique proposed need to work inside of a particle system. display as bounding a boxe is not an option. the whole point of proxies is that it still give an idea of the volumetry your object is going to take in the scene.

Comment: Either by converting the geometry to a *convex hull* or using the *decimate modifier* to get an approx geo representation...

Comment: Thanks for the decimate modifier proposal. unfortunately decimating a tree look like a mess. and for the Convec hull it's a really good step to achieve the geometry but how to hide/unhide render and on a particle system.

Comment: It won't look 'pretty', but, maybe shrinkwrap a sphere or whatever around the object?...